# Spring MVC - Return view with Ajax using POST and sending data

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I am trying to develop a simple component which job is to render particular portion of the data using a template.

I am using a Spring-Data-Rest-MVC so I've got a ready and working OOTB source of the data that suits my requirements (AJAX-based web app).

So, with what I am having problem with. 
The problem lies here:

```
{
  "panels":[
    {
      "id":"panel-BASIC",
      "el":"panel-BASIC",
      "attributes":[
        {
          "position":"0",
          "key":"id",
          "display":"value",
          "dataUtility":"",
          "value":"2"
        },
        {
          "position":"1",
          "key":"begin",
          "display":"value",
          "dataUtility":"",
          "value":1384518600000
        },
        {
          "position":"2",
          "key":"end",
          "display":"value",
          "dataUtility":"",
          "value":1384518600000
        },
        {
          "position":"3",
          "key":"interval",
          "display":"value",
          "dataUtility":"intervalCalculationDataUtility"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":"panel-ONE_TO_MANY",
      "el":"panel-ONE_TO_MANY",
      "attributes":[
        {
          "position":"0",
          "key":"tasks",
          "display":"table",
          "dataUtility":"",
          "value":"http://localhost:8080/rest/appointment/2/tasks"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":"panel-MANY_TO_ONE",
      "el":"panel-MANY_TO_ONE",
      "attributes":[
        {
          "position":"0",
          "key":"car",
          "display":"infopage",
          "dataUtility":"",
          "value":"http://localhost:8080/rest/appointment/2/car"
        },
        {
          "position":"1",
          "key":"assignee",
          "display":"infopage",
          "dataUtility":"",
          "value":"http://localhost:8080/rest/appointment/2/assignee"
        },
        {
          "position":"2",
          "key":"reporter",
          "display":"infopage",
          "dataUtility":"",
          "value":"http://localhost:8080/rest/appointment/2/reporter"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "container":"ip-SAppointment"
}
```

It's the descriptor which is being sent to the server, previously built in the client side using retrieved data and template descriptor.

Using a JSON I've posted I need to sent a POST request with it and than return rendered view.
The job of a controller method is rather simple:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/template/render",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ModelAndView getInfoPageViewData(
        @RequestBody final InfoPageDescriptor body
) {
    LOGGER.trace(String.format("/getInfoPageViewData -> %s", body));
    final ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    modelMap.put("dd", body);
    return new ModelAndView(DATA_VIEW_NAME, modelMap);
}
```

So as You can see it wraps the sent JSON into the InfoPageDescriptor bean which is placed than into ModelMap.

The returned view will process the bean from the model map and acts accordingly to entries.

Anyway I can get this method working. With the jQuery (AJAX-POST) call like this:

```
function loadRenderedView(url, data, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        headers : {
            'Accept'      : 'text/plain',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url     : url,
        data    : JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        type    : 'post',
        success : function (data) {
            callback.apply(this, [data, true]);
        },
        failure : function () {
            callback.apply(this, [data, false]);
        }
    });
}
```

I get an error: **The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**.

Could You give some hints of how I should built a request or controller-server method to make it work ?

Comment: Add "log4j.logger.org.springframework = INFO, yourlogger" to your log4j.properties and check traces, it seems you are sending a Json that does not match with the InfoPageDescriptor class.

Comment: Alright, I will take a look on that.

Comment: You saved my day, this small tip allowed me to find an error. Indeed my JSON structure did not match Java structure. One small nested property had different name. Thx for the help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, will post it as an answer, because I need to to have a formatting here.

@vzamanillo, Your assumption may be correct here, because I've checked the logs and got these exceptions:

```
2013-12-14 17:15:14 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Invalid media type "json": does not contain '/'
2013-12-14 17:15:14 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Invalid media type "json": does not contain '/'
2013-12-14 17:15:14 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Invalid media type "json": does not contain '/'
```

I think it can be about an URLs that are sent in the JSON, so I will investigate that.

Answer (score 1):

Add

Log4j.logger.org.springframework = INFO, yourlogger

to your log4j.properties and check traces, it seems you are sending a Json that does not match with the InfoPageDescriptor class.

EDIT:

change the dataType of stringify to "application/json" It maybe fix the issue and change the Accept header of the ajax request to

'Accept': 'application/json',

Comment: Well, it could be the issue...anyway it is fixed at the moment and I was able to retrieve the json and include the bean in the view to render it according to the template and the data.